# How to plot points on the image using with react-ionic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, heatmap

[image: 1280x720]I am facing the issue of plotting the heatmap with dynamic points, on the image which is coming from the server-side using the heatmap.js.

using the heatmap.js with the react-ionic.

I am able to plot the points on the desktop view but I want to plot it on the mobile view.

```
import React from "react";
import h337 from "heatmap.js";
import Image from './road.jpg'
import './styles.css'

interface IControlAreaProps {
    location?: any;
    state?: any;
    history?: any;
}

const App: React.FC<IControlAreaProps> = () => {

    const handleHeatmap = () => {

        let heatmapInstance = h337.create({
            container: document.querySelector('.heatmap'),
            gradient: {
                '1': 'blue',
            },
        });

       
        let points: any = [ 

            //with these point you can see the heatmap plotted on the image
             { x: 58, y: 63, value: 80 },
             { x: 28, y: 73, value: 90 },
             { x: 98, y: 83, value: 60 }

             // but these point heat map are not ploting
            //  { x: 588, y: 625, value: 50 },
            //  { x: 828, y: 465, value: 60 },
            //  { x: 460, y: 447, value: 40}
            ];
        let data = {
            max: 100,
            min: 0,
            data: points
        };
        heatmapInstance.setData(data);

        var div: any = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        div.style.display = div?.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
    }



    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleHeatmap} >
                showHeatMap
                </button>
            <div id="mydiv" className="heatmap">
                <img src={Image} alt="image"/>
                </div>
        </>

    );
};
export default App;
```

I am looking for a solution to how I can plot the heatmap on the image using dynamic points.
I have tried resizing the canvas and image.

and if there is any other way or library for plotting the heatmap on the image that also will be fine.

Comment: Is the issue that the x-y coordinates from your data don't match the image size?

Comment: @DrewReese it might be I am not sure if you want i can share the image too.

Comment: Image will help, also including a running codesandbox that reproduces issue may help more.

Comment: @DrewReese [https://codesandbox.io/s/heatmap-l3pjj?file=/src/App.tsx](codesandbox) link.